# Calculating with high numbers in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, primes

I am trying to code a prime finder in C++. I have a functioning program that I am happy with, but when I try to calculate primes in the billions I get error messages like this one:

> "Implicit conversion from 'long' to 'int' changes value from 10000000001 to 1410065409" .

It works reasonably fast even in the billions so I want to test the limits, but this number change stops that.

Comment: A signed int can only hold a value up to 2,147,483,647 so when you convert from a long (holding anything larger) to an int you end up with an overflow.

Comment: You can use `uint64_t` in order to increase the boundary up to `2^64-1`. Beyond that, you'll have to use an off the shelf Big-Integer class (or implement one of your own). BTW, you're expected to show your code as part of your question, so that others can refer to it when answering. In addition, not being able to understand the limits of variable types in C++ (`int`, `long`, etc) shows a fundamental lack of knowledge. No accusation made, but you're expected to do "some homwork" prior to posting a question. That said, at present your question is considered rather low-quality (no offense please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `long` type (can hold bigger numbers than int).
Here is an example how `int` would overflow:

```
int test1 = 10;
int test2 = test1 * 89000000;
cout << test2;
```

With long integers

```
long test1 = 10;
long test2 = test1 * 89000000;
cout << test2;
```

the result will be correct.